# I'm getting error "uninitialized constant SongsController" on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, uninitialized-constant

I'm getting an error like that, I'm new in rails.

my routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
get 'welcome' => 'page#search'

resources :songs
end
```

search.html.erb

```
<%=form_for @song do |f|%>
<%=f.text_field :search%>
<%=f.submit 'Search'%>
<%end%>
```

page_controller.rb

```
class PageController < ApplicationController
attr_accessor :a

def search
  @songs = Song.all
  @song = Song.new
end

def new
  @song = Song.new
end

def Create
  @song = Song.new()
 if @song.save 
  rediect_to ''
 else
  render new
 end
end

 def parameter
  params.require(@song)
 end
end
```

path

> welcome_path GET /welcome(.:format)  page#search 
>   song_new_path POST    /song/new(.:format) song#new 
>   songs_path    GET /songs(.:format)    songs#index 
>   POST  /songs(.:format)    songs#create 
>   new_song_path GET /songs/new(.:format)    songs#new 
>   edit_song_path    GET /songs/:id/edit(.:format)   songs#edit 
>   song_path GET /songs/:id(.:format)    songs#show 
>   PATCH /songs/:id(.:format)    songs#update
>       PUT   /songs/:id(.:format)    songs#update
>       DELETE    /songs/:id(.:format)    songs#destroy

Answer (score 1):

you declared `resources :songs` in your routes file, so Rails expecte SongsController inheriting from ApplicationController in your app/controllers folder. If you do not have this controller, create new file:

```
app/controller/songs_controller.rb

class SongsController < ApplicationController

  # add implementation of CRUD methods
  def index

  end

  def show

  end

  def new

  end

  # ...
end
```

Comment: I getting a new error Unable to autoload constant SongsController, expected /home/ubuntu/workspace/Hackstore/app/controllers/songs_controller.rb to define it

Comment: now error changed to Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant SongsController

Comment: my mistake, I wrote `app/controller/songs_controller.rb`, and forgot to add s to controller. The correct path:  `app/controllers/songs_controller.rb`

Answer (score 0):

Rename your controller as **SongsController**